# Using WMTS with Google maps Javascript API

Tags: google-maps, wmts

I am trying to learn and play around with the Google maps JavaScript API, KML, WMS, WMTS etc. I have a fair understanding of how to use KML files, Web Mapping Services, GeoJson files but I am struggling to use WMTS with the google maps API. I have gone through a lot of documentation on WMTS but could not find a working example. Could someone point me to one?

Comment: Here is some code to do WMTS https://www.procrastinatio.org/mercator/google.js the live demo is here https://www.procrastinatio.org/mercator/google.html

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the resources but perhaps I am looking for something even simpler. I was trying to use the 2 files (google.html and google.js) files in a stand alone way by removing the external dependencies but it didn't work out. I started getting a lot of 403 forbidden errors.